# bpkt ARM instruction freezes my embedded application

Tags: c, arm, iar

I am developing an application that I compile with the IAR Embedded Workbench solution. In this application, I have embedded the expat library - a tiny XML parser that works fine - which uses the `time()` standard function to generate a salt, as you can see in this chunk of code:

```
static unsigned long
generate_hash_secret_salt(void)
{
    unsigned int seed = time(NULL) % UINT_MAX;
    srand(seed);
    return rand();
}
```

It appears that the `time()` function works fine on semihosting mode (while debugging with the J-link JTAG device by Segger, I guess) but does not work at all when I am running my application without the j-link debugger.

So I've run into the assembly code of `time()` function - which actually appears to be a proprietary implementation by IAR - and saw this single instruction:

```
BPKT #0xab
```

By seeking information through the web, I came up with the following paragraph:

> If required, a debugger can use it to store additional information
>   about the breakpoint. ARM does not recommend the use of the BKPT instruction with an immediate
>   value set to 0xAB for any purpose other than Semi-hosting.

Is it due to such an issue? I must admit that my knowledge in ARM assembler is poor, and since I cannot debug my application while it is not on semi-hosting mode, I am pretty confused.

For your information, regardless of the argument you may pass to `time()`, it is always freezing in non semihosting mode.

Finally, what could you suggest me to do in order to bypass such an implementation? Shall I import another one into my C project? ...

Thanks

Comment: BKPT will put cpu into debug mode, you need to find a way to make build different to get rid of it. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHEDHIF.html

Comment: To me, this sounds like an `assert` or similar that is firing. Is it possible that your BSP (board support package) doesn't have the necessary functions to implement `time` and thus time says "Sorry can't do that".

Comment: Did you try to compile the code in Release Mode? Maybe that will make the BKPT instruction disappear.

Comment: Adi: looks like the Release Mode changes many things, I'll dig into... Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You're right that this breakpoint instruction is being used to trigger some kind of semihosting operation.  If your code contains such instructions, you'll need to always run it attached to a debugger that knows what to do when such an instruction is encountered.  If you need to run the device standalone, find out what code you're using that causes the semihosting operations to take place, and make sure that code isn't in the standalone build.  This situation is a good opportunity to set up "debug" and "release" builds of your software - maybe using `#ifdef DEBUG` or something along those lines to exclude the semihosting code from your release build.

In this *specific* case, it looks like your C library's `time` implementation is using semihosting to get the host time over the debugger connection.  You'll have to come up with a different solution if you want to run your program disconnected from the debugger.